# "The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST" message in my laravel API

Tags: laravel, api, ionic4

I followed a tutorial to do a login page with an external api, but my API is not working.

In the localhost http://localhost:8000/api/auth/login appear "The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST." and in the Chrome DevTools

```
headers: HttpHeaders {normalizedNames: Map(0), lazyUpdate: null, lazyInit: ƒ}
message: "Http failure response for http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/auth/register: 422 Unprocessable Entity"
name: "HttpErrorResponse"
ok: false
status: 422
statusText: "Unprocessable Entity"
url: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/auth/register"
```

I use laravel 6,php 7, ionic 4

Please, help me!

(tutorial is: https://blog.flicher.net/laravel-rest-api-passport-authentication-for-ionic-app/)

Comment: Check your routes. run `php artisan route:list` at root directory in cmd or terminal. Check `http verb` for the given route.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you follow the tutorial in section `Step 6 — Set API routes` it list down all routes for api.

Here it says as below

```
File: api.php 

Route::group([
    'prefix' => 'auth'
], function () {
    Route::post('login', 'Auth\AuthController@login')->name('login');
});
```

That means we have a route with name as `login` which would be a `POST` request and url would be `api/auth/login` as it is api.php file.

You are calling it from the browser, that would be a `get` request, which is not found by laravel in routes, so it is generating this error.

Reference: [Laravel Routing](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/routing)